# ASMX web service reference how to set equivalent to MaxReceivedMessageSize

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx, soap-client, soaphttpclientprotocol

Web Service is an ASMX web service (NOT WCF)

I am receiving an error

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element

I am using a proxy that Visual Studio generates for you when you add a "Web Reference" (please note that I am NOT adding "Service Reference", instead I am using Web Reference)... this creates a proxy that inherits from `SoapHttpClientProtocol`

Can anyone help me figure out how to set the equivalent to `MaxReceivedMessageSize` for this method? (I am asking for the equivalent of doing `HttpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue` if I were using WCF)

Comment: Could u post the config file?

Answer (score 4):

This message is WCF specific. I suspect then you are calling your ASMX service through a WCF client proxy (client class inherits from the `ClientBase`). On the other hand, a typical ASMX client proxy inherits from `SoapHttpClientProtocol`.

The trick is, if you just "Add Service Reference" from within the Visual Studio, the WCF-like proxy is created by default. In order to create an old-type proxy, you should click "Advanced" on the proxy creator dialog and then "Add web reference" on the advanced properties dialog or invoke the `wsdl.exe` tool from the command line.

The proxy created in an "old" doesn't have any message quotas.

Nevertheless, **using the legacy ASMX technology, both for the server and the client, is not recommended**.

Comment: Thanks for the response Wiktor... yes i am using "old" (Add Service Reference > Advanced > Add Web Reference). this creates a proxy that inherits from SoapHttpClientProtocol

Comment: Is there any documentation that suggests there is no message quotas for this "old" way?

Comment: I've been using it for years and there was no such limitation. Is the exception thrown from the client proxy or from the server then?

Answer (score 4):

The MaxReceivedMessageSize change can be done in the App.config file or in the source code before calling the service's method.

```
 BasicHttpBinding httpBinding = youAddWebServiceName.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Binding as BasicHttpBinding;
 httpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
```

Comment: From my understanding, MaxReceivedMessageSize  only applies to using WCF as the client, so this would not help in this case because OP specifically says they are using a web reference

Answer (score 4):

maybe it help someone. I get same error message in ASMX Web service but that's not from server! it was from client and i just add this to client config:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
<binding name="BindingName" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" maxBufferSize="20000000" />
</basicHttpBinding>
```